# Shared string in C++?

Tags: c++, string

Which "shared string" implementation for C++ would you recommend?

(Sorry if I missed a similar question. I had a look but could not find any)

Comment: Well, that depends on what framework you are using.

Comment: I heard that "shared strings" get out of style since sharing interferes with multithreading.

Comment: What do you mean by framework?
(Actually, what I need is that two separate strings containing the same character set allocate this character set only once)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the STL: `std::string` and `std::wstring`.

ONLY if you need something more fancy you could used the smart pointers to wrap your own implementation. These smart pointers are present in the new C++ STL or boost.

- `boost::shared_ptr` for example if
  you use it inside a DLL
- `boost::intrusive_ptr` works over DLL
  boundaries.

EDIT: Like remarked in the comments STL strings are not guaranteed to be immutable by nature. If you want them to be so, use the `const` specifier.

Comment: I guess by "shared string" the OP meant copy-on-write semantics, which the STL strings don't provide.

Comment: OK he should use `const std::string` or `const std::wstring`, fully correct. Thanks.

Comment: @Lukáš: The STL string was designed to allow for copy-on-write (COW) implementations; and there are some STL implementations that actually use COW. It went a little bit out of favour, after Herb Sutter showed that naive COW can slow down things considerably (e.g. here http://gotw.ca/publications/optimizations.htm).

Comment: @stephan: true, but the problem is that you can't be sure that as you switch compilers/libraries the implementation will stay the same

Comment: High-level operations in a language always cost you something extra. With atomic integers the price is not too high, and you have less pain than with pointers, faster code than always making a copy.

Comment: you can also go the way other languages do (StringBuilder in Java & C#) with stringstreams... Modification of the string in place is also not always easy: if you append another string and the resulting length is beyond the reserved space, then you also have to realloc... But I agree for strings with a length within a given range, it's definitively faster.

Answer (score 1):

std::(w)string can be shared, but this is not mandated by the standard. [QString](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qstring.html#details) uses an [atomic refcount](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/shared.html#implicit-sharing) for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting with the standard strings, `std::string` and `std::wstring`.

However, there's one caveat:

Neither of the two string classes enforces a particular encoding. If you want your application to behave well when dealing with other locales or other languages than English, you should either start with std::wstring, or use something like [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) which lets you deal with UTF-8 strings.

As [Joel Spolsky pointed out](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), you *have to* know which encoding your strings are in to handle them correctly.

Comment: You generally don't have to do anything special to handle international characters with UTF-8 encoded `std::string`s. Just don't assume that a single byte corresponds to a single character. With the exception that any byte < 128 corresponds to a single ASCII character of that codepoint, so you are safe if you split strings on or search for ASCII characters (e.g. "=" or ",") in UTF-8 strings.

I wouldn't recommend using `std::wstring` since the strings are not compatible with 1-byte char APIs. And don't use a library to help you handle UTF-8 strings until you're sure it's necessary.